# Подсчитать количество чисел в заданном диапазоне куб которых оканчивается на 4 или 9

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Количество чисел**

На вход программе подаются два целых числа a и b (a≤b). Напишите программу, которая подсчитывает количество чисел в диапазоне от a до b включительно, куб которых оканчивается на 4 или 9.

**Формат входных данных**

На вход программе подаются два целых числа a и b (a≤b).

**Формат выходных данных**

Программа должна вывести одно целое число в соответствии с условием программы.
Примечание. Куб числа aa – это его третья степень a^3a.

Sample Input 1:

```
1
10

counter = 0
for i in range(int(input()), int(input())):
    if i % 10 == 4:
        counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
    else:
        i % 10 == 9
        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Но спасибо, что объяснили нам, что такое куб числа. а то я лично места себе не находил.

Comment: Выше указанный ваш исходник абсолютно не правильный!!! Читайте задачу внимательнее!!!!!!

Comment: ну я не понимаю(((( 'Eгор' , 'strawdog'

Comment: @Егор, если бы у автора вопроса все бы получилось сделать самостоятельно, то в чем был бы смысл задавать вопрос??

Comment: @MaxU, Так он не к чему не научиться данный форум не площадка для обучений. Разве нет?!

Comment: опят ссоры, я обратился сюда дк мой ментор не отвечает. Иначе  я бы не написал сюда!

Comment: @Егор, сейчас вопрос соответствует правилам форума. Есть вопрос, есть попытка собственного решения...

Comment: @MaxU, OK))))))

Comment: @gipotezaizgaza, вы проверяете последнюю цифру числа из диапазона, вместо того , чтобы проверять последнюю цифру __куба этого числа__

Comment: @MaxU понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если обратить внимание на кубы чисел, которые заканчиваются на 4 и 9, то можно увидеть закономерность - если число заканчивается на 4 или на 9, то и куб этого числа будет заканчиваться на ту же цифру:

```
In [81]: [(i, i**3) for i in range(70) if (i**3) % 10 in (4,9)]
Out[81]: 
[(4, 64),
 (9, 729),
 (14, 2744),
 (19, 6859),
 (24, 13824),
 (29, 24389),
 (34, 39304),
 (39, 59319),
 (44, 85184),
 (49, 117649),
 (54, 157464),
 (59, 205379),
 (64, 262144),
 (69, 328509)]
```

поэтому ответ можно получить аналитически:

```
def f(a, b, digit):
    a = a // 10 * 10 + digit
    b = b // 10 * 10 - (10 - digit)
    return (b - a + 10) // 10

def calc(a, b):
    return f(a, b, 4) + f(a, b, 9)

a, b = 123, 321

res = calc(a, b)
```

результат:

```
In [185]: res
Out[185]: 40
```

проверка:

```
In [186]: len([(i, i**3) for i in range(a, b+1) if (i**3) % 10 in (4,9)])
Out[186]: 40
```

Answer (score 5):

Пояснения насчет кубов: 3 в кубе= 27, оканчивается на семь; 4 в кубе= 64, оканчивается на 4 - подходит нам по условию задачи. Нам надо "выловить" эту конечную цифру числа, проверить (вдруг она является 4-кой или 9-кой) и подсчитать количество таких случаев в заданном диапазоне.

Вот кубы первых 9 чисел (можете сами себе такой цикл составить, чтобы на них посмотреть и лучше понять, что просят сделать):

```
1**3 = 1
2**3 = 8
3**3 = 27
4**3 = 64
5**3 = 125
6**3 = 216
7**3 = 343
8**3 = 512
9**3 = 729
```

Comment: А еще, последние цифры кубов повторяются циклично из десятка в десяток. Мало того, 4 и 9, и только они, всегда в кубе дают соответственно 4 и 9.

Answer (score 2):

Может сразу прийти такое решение в голову:

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())
counter = 0
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if i ** 3 % 10 == 4 or i ** 3 % 10 == 9:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Но если внимательно вникнуть в задание, то можно понять, что нет смысла напрягать компьютер лишний раз и можно не возводить в куб числа:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
counter = 0
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    if i % 10 == 4 or i % 10 == 9:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```